# How does $f(A^c)$ compare to $f(A)^c$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a map of sets and $A \subset X$. I'm trying to compare $f(A^c)$ to $f(A)^c$.

From drawing a picture, I believe $f(A^c) \subset f(A)^c$ provided that $f$ is injective.

**Proof of conjecture 1.** Suppose $y \in f(A^c)$. Then there exists $x \in A^c$ such that $y = f(x)$. As $f$ is injective, for any $x' \in X$ satisfying $f(x') = y = f(x)$, we have $x = x'$, so for every $a \in A$, $f(a) \neq y$, so $y \not \in f(A)$, so $y \in f(A)^c$.

I think we have $f(A)^c \subset f(A^c)$ provided that $f$ is surjective.

**Proof of conjecture 2.** Let $y \in f(A)^c$. Then $y \not \in f(A)$. But, as $f$ is surjective, there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$, so $x \not \in A$, so $x \in A^c$, so $y \in f(A^c)$.

I believe these statements can be strengthened to biconditionals, but I haven't been able to figure out how to prove the reverse implications. Do I exhibit functions where $f(A^c) \not \subset f(A)^c$ when $f$ is not injective and $f(A)^c \not \subset f(A^c)$ when $f$ is not surjective?

Comment: If you want to make an iff statement like "$f$ is injective only when $f(A^c) = f(A)^c$", you have to add a quantifier for the set $A$ - namely, $f(A^c) = f(A)^c$ should hold over *every* set $A$. In that case, it may be true that $f$ must be injective. You can try proving it by contradiction - if $f$ were *not* injective, there would be points $x \neq y$ with $f(x) \neq f(y)$. From these points, can you then specify a set $A$ for which $f(A^c) \neq f(A)^c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to the correction suggested by Rob Bland, your conjectures are correct. In fact the following results hold. Let $f: X \to Y$ be a function.

**Proposition 1**. The following conditions are equivalent:

1. $f$ is injective,
2. for every subset $A$ of $X$, $f(A^c) \subseteq f(A)^c$,
3. for every one-element subset $A$ of $X$, $f(A^c) \subseteq f(A)^c$.

**Proof**. You already proved (1) implies (2) and (2) implies (3) is trivial.

(3) implies (1): Let $x \not= y$ and let $A = \{x\}$. Then $y \in a^c$, whence by (2), $f(y) \in f(A^c) \subseteq \{f(x)\}^c$. Thus $f(x) \not= f(y)$, as required.

**Proposition 2**. The following conditions are equivalent:

1. $f$ is surjective,
2. for every subset $A$ of $X$, $f(A)^c \subseteq f(A^c)$,
3. $f(\emptyset)^c \subseteq f(\emptyset^c)$.

**Proof**. You already proved (1) implies (2) and (2) implies (3) is trivial. But (3) implies (1) is also trivial since $f(\emptyset)^c =  \emptyset^c= Y$ and $f(\emptyset^c) = f(X)$, so that (3) just says that $Y \subseteq f(X)$.